# Failed to compare strings in jsp

Tags: struts2

I have a url that looks like this

....aaa=bbb&tab=second

in jsp I compare:

```
<s:if test="%{#parameters['tab']=='second'}">
```

it returns false....
I can see the value 'second' from here:

```
<s:property value="#parameters['tab']"/>
```

but this displays false:

```
<s:property value="%{#parameters['tab']=='second'}"/>
```

Any idea why it does that?
Thank you,
Yuri

Comment: I'd double-check the type of `#parameters['tab']`, it might be an array, since a named parameter can have multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parameters returns string array not string. Yes, a named parameters might have multiple values like tab=first&tab=second that's why it's string array instead of string.

```
<s:if test="%{#parameters['tab'][0]=='second'}">

</s:if>
```